# 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000. When trying to access the insert function of multimap

Tags: c++, stl, function-pointers

I was coding for one of the problems in USACO Training Page, and when I tried to debug my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<map>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;
int translate(string &s) {
    int n = s.length();
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        int n1 = 0;
        if (s.at(i) == 'Q' || s.at(i) == 'Z') {
            return -1;
        }
        switch (s.at(i)) {
        case 'A':
        case 'B':
        case'C':
            result = result + 2 * pow(10, n-1);
            n--;
            break;
        case 'D':
        case 'E':
        case'F':
            result = result + 3 * pow(10, n - 1);
            n--;
            break;
        case 'G':
        case 'H':
        case 'I':
            result = result + 4 * pow(10, n - 1);
            n--;
            break;
        case 'J':
        case 'K':
        case 'L':
            result = result + 5 * pow(10, n - 1);
            n--;
            break;
        case 'M':
        case 'N':
        case 'O':
            result = result + 6 * pow(10, n - 1);
            n--;
            break;
        case 'P':
        case 'R':
        case 'S':
            result = result + 7 * pow(10, n - 1);
            n--;
            break;
        case 'T':
        case 'U':
        case 'V':
            result = result + 8 * pow(10, n - 1);
            n--;
            break;
        case 'W':
        case 'X':
        case 'Y':
            result = result + 9 * pow(10, n - 1);
            n--;
            break;
    }
    }
    return result;
}
bool mycompare(int n, int m) {
    string a, b;
    a = to_string(n);
    b = to_string(m);
    if (a < b) {
        return true;
    }
    else return false;
}
int main() {
    bool(*ptr)(int, int);
    typedef multimap<int, string, bool(*)(int, int)> mmid;
    mmid pairs(ptr);
    string s1;
    ifstream inFile("dict.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);
    while (cin>>s1) {
        int f =translate(s1);
        pairs.insert(mmid::value_type(f, s1));
    }
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    multimap<int, string>::iterator it;
    while (true) {
        it = pairs.find(m);
        if (it != pairs.end()) {
            cout << it->second << endl;
            pairs.erase(it);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

When I try to enter"ANDY HARRY", when it processes to the second entry,

```
pairs.insert(mmid::value_type(f, s1));
```

At this line it gives me the code of 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x00000000.  What is wrong with my code?  And why is it giving me the error message not on the first entry but on the second one?  Thanks.

Comment: Where do you set the comparison object since you are overriding the standard comparison object?

Comment: "when I tried to debug my code" - It sounds like you really mean _test_ rather than debug. Well, now your test has revealed a _bug_, so you need to *de*stroy it. The way to debug is to use a debugger! With one, you would be able to run a stack trace after failure (or at any arbitrary break point) to see the exact call chain of functions leading to the problem, and from there you could identify its cause. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Why do you have an infinite `while` loop at the end of your program?

Comment: The comparison object is set as the mycompare function in the code, and I just changed the while loop to a finite one.

Comment: "set in the code" where? It isn't. The only reference to `mycompare` here is its definition. Hey, here's an idea: post the actual code you're actually using. Judging by what you've posted here, you never set the comparison function, so it's a null pointer, so when you insert the 2nd record, it tries to compare them by calling a null pointer, and splat. Next.

Comment: The code posted is the code I am actually using, and in this code there is a function called 'mycompare' which is used as the comparison function.

Comment: `ANDY HARRY` -- If this is actually the data, the `cin` will not read the "HARRY" part of the string due to the space delimiter.

Comment: At what point in your code do you tell the map to use `mycompare` as the comparison function? Show me.

Comment: typedef multimap<int, string, bool(*)(int, int)> mmid;

Comment: That just specifies the _type_ of function the map is supposed to use. There can be infinite functions of a given type. Nowhere do you tell it **which** function of that type to call. So, it calls the default, a null pointer, which is undefined behaviour. Please read the documentation of a container before using it and particularly before asking questions about it. That of `map` will quickly show you how to set its comparator.

Comment: @harry47341 That doesn't tell the map anything about what the actual function it is supposed to use.  Second, you really shouldn't be using `pow` to compute integral powers of 10.  There is no guarantee it will give the correct results since `pow` is a *floating point* function.

Comment: I am sorry for my ignorance.  I will read more about pointer to a function.

Comment: When using pointer to function you should make sure that you will actually point it to something. Also function pointers sucks. Prefer function objects: more optimisation opportunities, less chance to do something wrong, no need to provide constructor argument to map.

Comment: Also, if that string is longer than 10 or 11 characters, your `translate` function will go haywire since the result of `pow` will overflow the integer (unless you're compiler is using a mighty big integer types).

Comment: Thanks, I will not use pow function in my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is in this code:

```
bool(*ptr)(int, int);
mmid pairs(ptr);
```

In the first line, you define a function pointer named `ptr`, but you leave it uninitialized. This means that when you initialize `pairs` with `ptr`, you're initializing it with a garbage comparison function pointer.

To fix this, pass in the actual comparison function you want to use. For example:

```
mmid pairs(mycompare);
```

Additionally, this code is quite suspicious:

```
multimap<int, string>::iterator it;
it = pairs.find(m);
```

Notice that the type of the `multimap` doesn't match the type of `pairs`, so there's no a priori reason to suspect this iterator would work correctly. Consider this instead:

```
mmid::iterator it;
```

Comment: To clarify for the OP, in this case the function pointer _happened_ to be `0` a.k.a. the null pointer, but it _can_ be anything - or nothing! - because reading an unitialised variable is undefined behaviour. And to repeat my answer to the final question from the comments: the reason this doesn't occur on the 1st `insert()` is because the `map` doesn't need to (can't) compare.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested and it worked.  Thank you.