# Why doesn't g++ report warnings when passing uninitalized values into functions by const reference?

Tags: c++, initialization, g++, compiler-warnings

I was looking over the code given [in this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38254209/501557), which included code that's essentially the following:

```
bool (*uninitializedFunctionPointer)(int, int);
typedef std::multimap<int, std::string, bool(*)(int, int)> MultiMapType;
MultiMapType myMap(uninitializedFunctionPointer);
```

Notice that (as its name suggests) `uninitializedFunctionPointer` is an uninitlized function pointer that's passed into the constructor of `myMap`. Strangely enough, when I compiled this code with g++ 4.8.4 with `-Wall -Werror`, it compiled this code without reporting any warnings. However, it *did* report an error for this similar code:

```
bool (*uninitializedFunctionPointer)(int, int);
uninitializedFunctionPointer(137, 42);
```

Since calling the function pointer triggered a warning but passing it into the `multimap` constructor did not, I figured that g++ just didn't care about passing uninitialized values as parameters to functions. However, this code does indeed trigger a warning:

```
void doSomething(bool (*function)(int, int)) {
    function(137, 42); // Problem if 'function' is uninitialized
}

bool (*uninitializedFunctionPointer)(int, int);
doSomething(uninitializedFunctionPointer); // Warning!
```

I went to the [cppreference documentation for `multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/multimap) and saw that the `multimap` constructor takes in its comparator by const reference, so I tried writing this code:

```
typedef bool (*FunctionType)(int, int);
void doSomething(const FunctionType &function) {
    function(137, 42); // Problem if 'function' is uninitialized
}

bool (*uninitializedFunctionPointer)(int, int);
doSomething(uninitializedFunctionPointer);
```

And, surprisingly, this code compiles completely fine with no warnings at all. I figured that this might have something to do with function pointers, but it looks like that's not the case! Here's related code that just uses plain old integers:

```
void doSomething(const int &value) {
    std::cout << value << std::endl; // Problem if value is uninitialized
}

int uninitializedInt;
doSomething(uninitializedInt);
```

This code compiles with no warnings at all, even with `-Wall` enabled.

I understand that the compiler isn't required to issue warnings for all kinds of programming errors, but it seems highly unusual that g++ would detect a direct use of an uninitialized variable and an attempt to pass an uninitialized variable into a function by value, but would not report an issue when passing an uninitialized variable into a function *by const reference.*

Is there a compelling reason why g++ would not report a warning here? As in, is there reasonable code where an uninitialized variable could be passed into a function by const reference without triggering some sort of undefined behavior? Or is this just an oversight in the compiler?

Comment: The function could *store* a reference or pointer to the uninitialized variable and then read its value later after it has been initialized. I would make this into an answer except that I can't think of a specific example off the top of my head. But I suspect it's common enough so that warning in this case would be noise.

Comment: @Brian: All CRTP code depends on this functionality to work.

Comment: @MooingDuck Does CRTP actually use this? It uses forward declarations of types, but that's in the type system rather than runtime variables.

Comment: @templatetypedef: thinking on it more, you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem comes in because, given a reference, it is possible for the function to store a pointer or reference.

```
typedef bool (*FunctionType)(int, int);

FunctionType *stored_function;

void doSomething(const FunctionType &function)
{
     stored_function = const_cast<FunctionType *>(&function);
}

void doSomethingElse(int a, int b)
{
     (*stored_function)(a, b);
}

bool a_function(int, int)
{
    // do something
    return false;
}


int main()
{
    FunctionType func;
    doSomething(func);

    func = a_function;

    doSomethingElse(1,2);
}
```

This will result in `doSomethingElse()` calling `a_function()`, whether the assignment to `func` occurs before or after the call of `doSomething()`.   If the function definitions are in different compilation units, and the compiler warns about such things, code like the above would give spurious warnings in some cases.

There are similar techniques involving the function storing the reference or pointer as a member of a returned object, which will later be used by the caller.   If the constructor of such an object initialises a const reference or pointer using the passed reference, the `const_cast` I've used here would not be required.

Whether it is a good idea for a developer to use such techniques is another story - I certainly think the above is poor technique.   But developers who use such techniques tend to be vocal in their complaints about "spurious" warnings - including in some commercial libraries - so compiler vendors will prefer not to issue warnings.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this. doSomething violates const rules and generates a compilation error under g++: error: invalid conversion from 'bool (* const*)(int, int)' to 'bool (**)(int, int)' [-fpermissive].

Comment: Oh, ok, I think I get it, but as written the example code won't compile for a number of reasons. At the least, stored_function needs to be a pointer to const FunctionType. (I would fix it but all I have right now is an iPad and editing on these things is murder.)